# Convert tree to flat array

Tags: php

I'm having trouble turning a tree structure into a flat structure. My tree structure looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "X",
    "label": "X",
    "data": {
      "23": 1,
      "26": 2,
      "20": 38944000
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "Y",
        "label": "Y",
        "data": {
          "23": 303000,
          "26": 704000,
          "20": 2486000
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "Z",
            "label": "Z",
            "data": {
              "23": 0,
              "26": 0,
              "20": 2486000
            },
            "children": [],
            "level": 2,
            "type": "category"
          },
          {
            "id": "A",
            "label": "A",
            "data": {
              "23": 303000,
              "26": 704000,
              "20": 0
            },
            "children": [],
            "level": 2,
            "type": "category"
          }
        ],
        "level": 1,
        "type": "company"
      },
      {
        "id": "B",
        "label": "B",
        "data": {
          "23": 9627000,
          "26": 9580000,
          "20": 9428000
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "C",
            "label": "C",
            "data": {
              "23": 6021000,
              "26": 6030000,
              "20": 9428000
            },
            "children": [],
            "level": 2,
            "type": "category"
          },
          {
            "id": "D",
            "label": "D",
            "data": {
              "23": 2205000,
              "26": 1932000,
              "20": 0
            },
            "children": [],
            "level": 2,
            "type": "category"
          },
          {
            "id": "E",
            "label": "E",
            "data": {
              "23": 737000,
              "26": 874000,
              "20": 0
            },
            "children": [],
            "level": 2,
            "type": "category"
          },
          {
            "id": "F",
            "label": "F",
            "data": {
              "23": 664000,
              "26": 744000,
              "20": 0
            },
            "children": [],
            "level": 2,
            "type": "category"
          }
        ],
        "level": 1,
        "type": "company"
      }
    ],
    "level": 0,
    "type": "client"
  }
]
```

And I want to turn it into a structure:

```
[
  {
    "client": "X",
    "company": "Y",
    "category": "Z",
    "23": 0,
    "26": 0,
    "20": 2486000
  },
  {
    "client": "X",
    "company": "Y",
    "category": "A",
    "23": 303000,
    "26": 704000,
    "20": 0
  },
  {
    "client": "X",
    "company": "B",
    "category": "C",
    "23": 6021000,
    "26": 6030000,
    "20": 9428000
  },
  {
    "client": "X",
    "company": "B",
    "category": "D",
    "23": 2205000,
    "26": 1932000,
    "20": 0
  },
  {
    "client": "X",
    "company": "B",
    "category": "E",
    "23": 664000,
    "26": 744000,
    "20": 0
  },
  {
    "client": "X",
    "company": "B",
    "category": "F",
    "23": 664000,
    "26": 744000,
    "20": 0
  }
]
```

I try with this:

```
/**
     * Prepare flat data array.
     *
     * @param CompareForecastsReportDto $report
     * @param GetCompareForecastsReportQuery $query
     */
    private function prepareFlatTable(
        CompareForecastsReportDto $report,
        GetCompareForecastsReportQuery $query
    ): void
    {
        $this->prepareHeaderColumns($report, $query);
        $flatData = [];

        foreach ($report->getData() as $dataRow) {
            $data = $this->flatten($dataRow);

            $flatData[] = $data;
        }
var_dump($flatData);exit;
        $this->setFlatData($flatData);
    }

    /**
     * To flat array.
     *
     * @param CompareReportRowDto $compareReportRowDto
     *
     * @return CompareReportRowDto[]
     */
    private function flatten(
        CompareReportRowDto $compareReportRowDto
    ): array {
        $result = [];

        $result = array_merge($result, [$compareReportRowDto->getType() => $compareReportRowDto->getLabel()]);
        foreach($compareReportRowDto->getChildren() as $item) {
            if (count($item->getChildren())) {
                $result = array_merge($result, $this->flatten($item));
            }

            $result = array_merge($result, [$item->getType() => $item->getLabel()]);
            $result = array_merge($result, $item->getData());
```

But result is not correct.

Its important to use recursive.

By using answer of trincot my function finally looks like:

```
/**
     * To flat array.
     *
     * @param CompareReportRowDto $compareReportRowDto
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function flatten(
        CompareReportRowDto $compareReportRowDto
    ): array {
        $result = [];

        foreach($compareReportRowDto->getChildren() as $item) {
            if (count($item->getChildren())) {
                foreach($this->flatten($item) as $deeper) {
                    $result[] = [$compareReportRowDto->getType() => $compareReportRowDto->getLabel()] + [$item->getType() => $item->getLabel()] + $deeper;
                }
            } else {
                $result[] = [$compareReportRowDto->getType() => $compareReportRowDto->getLabel()] + [$item->getType() => $item->getLabel()] + $item->getData();
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: In your first JSON structure there are syntax errors. Colons missing after property names, and are you sure your property names include a terminating point?

Comment: Sorry, now JSON should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this recursive function:

```
function flatten($children) {
    $result = [];
    foreach($children as $child) {
        if (count($child->children) == 0) {
            $result[] = [
                $child->type => $child->id,
                "23" => $child->data->{23},
                "26" => $child->data->{26},
                "20" => $child->data->{20},
            ];
        } else {
            foreach(flatten($child->children) as $deeper) {
                $result[] = [$child->type => $child->id] + $deeper;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Assuming you have the JSON text in variable `$json`, you could use it as follows:

```
$tree = json_decode($json);
$result = flatten($tree);
print_r($result);
```

See it run on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ZFGNL)

Comment: Oh sorry I forget to add one important thing it must be recursive because childrens can be in many depths.

Comment: Updated to a recursive function.